# php issue with xpath. Need to replace some values on xml structure

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I need to replace some values on an XML structure [like this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1scKFuukeKUuMeC2rN4dswI5q6b_1HgSb/view?usp=sharing).

The file structure is known as long as namespace declared but I cannot scan it through xpath library:

```
$xmlDoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
foreach($xmlDoc->getDocNamespaces() as $strPrefix => $strNamespace) {
    if(strlen($strPrefix) == 0) $strPrefix = "a"; //Assign an arbitrary namespace prefix.
    $xmlDoc->registerXPathNamespace($strPrefix,$strNamespace);
}
print_r($xmlDoc->xpath("//a:MapData/Layouts/Layout/Dimension"));
```

What's wrong on my approach?

My goal is to replace `/MapData/Layouts/Layout` child values and measure unit from:

```
    <Layout LayoutId="Stepper/Litho001" DefaultUnits="micron" >
        <Dimension X="1" Y="1" />
        <LowerLeft X="-54600" Y="80000" />
        <DeviceSize X="16690" Y="23890" />
        <StepSize X="16800" Y="24000" />
        <ChildLayouts>
            <ChildLayout LayoutId="Stepper/Litho/Reticle001" />
        </ChildLayouts>
    </Layout>
```

to

```
    <Layout LayoutId="Stepper/Litho001" DefaultUnits="mm" >
        <Dimension X="1" Y="1" />
        <LowerLeft X="-54.600" Y="80.000" />
        <DeviceSize X="16.690" Y="23.890" />
        <StepSize X="16.800" Y="24.000" />
        <ChildLayouts>
            <ChildLayout LayoutId="Stepper/Litho/Reticle001" />
        </ChildLayouts>
    </Layout>
```

Starting from source file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1scKFuukeKUuMeC2rN4dswI5q6b_1HgSb/view?usp=sharing

My goal is to get an xml like this:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/18O6COF3qH8HijX6cZqXHsmNJKQSTyMoQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is it only the nodes shown that are to be modified?

Comment: no. they aren't. I need to work on several nodes of the example xml linked to my post to perform some changes as translate any measure from microns to mm as long, or change text on <BinCode>FFFFFF(...)</BinCode> to <BinCode>000(...)</BinCode>, or ....

Comment: fair enough but with, for example, the `Dimension` node and it's two attributes `x` and `y` - in the `from` these are 1 and in the `to` they are still 1 - there seems to be no means to determine which nodes should or should not be divided by 1000 to give the `mm` value

Comment: The editing of the XML by PHP is easy enough - but without some idea of what does or does not need this conversion this remains quite a task. Can whatever app that processes this XML not make that adjustment instead?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I made a modification on my post putting the source xml file (to be modified) and the destination file (that I need to get after modification).

Comment: I rather think that you might have missed the point. I more or less understand the aim but what is not clear is which attributes must be transformed by simple arithmetic operations or hex/binary conversion. If one were to do the division by 1000 on all attributes that are numeric it would not work - the result would be incorrect. For example `<BinDefinition BinCode="01" BinCount="4928" BinQuality="Pass" BinDescription="GOOD" />` has numeric attribute values in both XML files... You NEED to determine the rules for conversion first